# Probability Jaccard Similarity in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Anyone has any idea how to efficiently implement a 2D **probability** Jaccard similarity algorithm in numpy? It looks like this specific algorithm is almost non-existent in computer vision (not in pytorch, not in tensorflow nor in skilearn, I wonder is there a specific reason for this). The formula for probability Jaccard similarity is (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Optimality_of_the_Probability_Jaccard_Index)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. It's pretty straightforward, we use broadcasting to perform the divisions of all pair of points without loops:

```
def jaccard_probability(x,y):
    # Ignore  == 0 terms
    x0 = x[x!=0]
    y0 = y[y!=0]
    
    jac = np.sum(
        1.0 / np.sum(np.maximum(x0[:,None] / x0, y0[:,None] / y0), axis=0)
        )
    
    return jac
```

However, I suggest you read the NumPy guide to get a grasp of the basics, at least of broadcasting, as it is a very useful tool to know if you plan on using NumPy in the future and want to make efficient code!